# Chatter ConnectAPI getRecommendationForUser Error

Tags: apex, chatter

I'm trying to get list of recommended users to follow using ConnectAPI method getRecommendationForUser.

Syntax from the docs,
**getRecommendationForUser(String, String, ConnectApi.RecommendationActionType, String) 
Returns the recommendation for the context user for the specified action and object ID.**

What I'm trying to do,

List values = ConnectApi.RecommendationActionType.values();
System.debug(ConnectApi.getRecommendationForUser('Internal',userinfo.getuserID(), values[0], userinfo.getuserID())); // values[0] is follow;

I get compilation error **Method does not exist or incorrect signature: ConnectApi.getRecommendationForUser(String, String, ConnectApi.RecommendationActionType, String)**

Not sure what is the mistake in the syntax. Can anyone see any syntax issues?
Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the name of the class. The method call should be like this:

ConnectApi.Recommendations.getRecommendationForUser(...)